# how to put java class into the gemfire key-value struct

Tags: gemfire, geode

gfsh>put --key=('id':'133abg125') --value=('firstname':'James','lastname':'Gosling')  --region=/region --key-class=data.ProfileKey --value-class=data.ProfileDetails

Message : ClassNotFoundException data.ProfileKey
Result  : false

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your domain classes are available on all servers as well. I'd suggest starting them with the `--classpath <jarfile>` option and pointing them at the jar containing the relevant classes.

Comment: Option 'classpath' is not available for this command - when trying to run the put command with --classpath. But I suppose you suggest starting the servers with that classpath...